Android app to list and export purchased apps
I had an app that does this in the past.
It was called Purchased Apps.
To be clear, I still have the app installed on my phone, and I've extracted the .apk - but it is no longer in the Play Store, here is the original app's link:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.azefsw.purchasedapps
The features I used:

Get a list of apps in my library (whether installed or not)
Filtering options (any combination of):

Installed / not-installed
Purchase type: In-App / No In-app
Excluding "Free" Purchases - this is a key feature, filtering out all 'free' promotions.


Export list as csv: Name, Price, purchase date, link to app on play store

Does anyone know about a different app that does this?
